# ¿que error me esta generando el php que no me deja editar mi pdo?

Tags: php, pdo

buen dia y gracias por su tiempo.

estoy practicando para enlazar una base de datos con php ya me deja eliminar pero cuando quiero agregar me sale el siguiente error: he buscado pero no encuentro el error en mi codigo. y me sigue enviando este error:

Notice: Undefined index: QUIEN_REGISTRA in C:\xampp\htdocs\Formulario prueba\index.php on line 87

Notice: Undefined index: ASOCIADO in C:\xampp\htdocs\Formulario prueba\index.php on line 89

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\Formulario prueba\index.php on line 136
Array ( [0] => HY093 [1] => [2] => )

el codigo es el siguiente.

```
<?php
    
if(isset($_POST['insertar'])){
///////////// Informacion enviada por el formulario /////////////
//////////// $ID_ACTIVIDAD=$_POST['ID ACTIVIDAD']; /////////////

$CONSECUTIVO_X_CASO=$_POST['CONSECUTIVO_X_CASO'];
$CASO=$_POST['CASO'];
$FECHA_ACTIVIDAD= date('Y-m-d');
$CARPETA=$_POST['CARPETA'];
$TIPO_DE_ACTIVIDAD=$_POST['TIPO_DE_ACTIVIDAD'];
$DETALLE_ACTIVIDAD_1=$_POST['DETALLE_ACTIVIDAD_1'];
$DETALLE_ACTIVIDAD_2=$_POST['DETALLE_ACTIVIDAD_2'];
$RESPONSABLE=$_POST['RESPONSABLE'];
$QUIEN_REGISTRA=$_POST['QUIEN_REGISTRA'];
$PARA_INFORME=$_POST['PARA_INFORME'];
$ASOCIADO=$_POST['ASOCIADO'];
$SOLICITUD_ASOCIADA=$_POST['SOLICITUD_ASOCIADA'];
$OBSERVACIONES=$_POST['OBSERVACIONES'];
$PRUEBA_ALGO=$_POST['PRUEBA_ALGO'];
$QUE_PRUEBA_O_DESVIRTUA=$_POST['QUE_PRUEBA_O_DESVIRTUA'];
$RELACION_EMP=$_POST['RELACION_EMP'];
$NOTAS_PROBATORIAS=$_POST['NOTAS_PROBATORIAS'];
$PARA_PREPARATORIA=$_POST['PARA_PREPARATORIA'];
$TESTIGO_INCORPORA=$_POST['TESTIGO_INCORPORA'];
$ORDEN_PREPARATORIA=$_POST['ORDEN_PREPARATORIA'];
$FECHA_DE_REGISTRO= date('Y-m-d');
$SD_ACTIVIDAD1=$_POST['SD_ACTIVIDAD1'];
$SD_ACTIVIDAD2=$_POST['SD_ACTIVIDAD2'];
$SD_ACTIVIDAD3=$_POST['SD_ACTIVIDAD3'];
///////// Fin informacion enviada por el formulario /// 

////////////// Insertar a la tabla la informacion generada /////////
$sql="insert into diario(CONSECUTIVO_X_CASO, CASO, FECHA_ACTIVIDAD, CARPETA, TIPO_DE_ACTIVIDAD, DETALLE_ACTIVIDAD_1, DETALLE_ACTIVIDAD_2, RESPONSABLE, QUIEN_REGISTRA, PARA_INFORME, ASOCIADO, SOLICITUD_ASOCIADA, OBSERVACIONES, PRUEBA_ALGO, QUE_PRUEBA_O_DESVIRTUA, RELACION_EMP, NOTAS_PROBATORIAS, PARA_PREPARATORIA, TESTIGO_INCORPORA, ORDEN_PREPARATORIA, FECHA_DE_REGISTRO, SD_ACTIVIDAD1, SD_ACTIVIDAD2, SD_ACTIVIDAD3) values(:CONSECUTIVO_X_CASO, :CASO, :FECHA_ACTIVIDAD, :CARPETA, :TIPO_DE_ACTIVIDAD, :DETALLE_ACTIVIDAD_1, :DETALLE_ACTIVIDAD_2, :RESPONSABLE, :QUIEN_REGISTRA, :PARA_INFORME, :ASOCIADO, :SOLICITUD_ASOCIADA, :OBSERVACIONES, :PRUEBA_ALGO, :QUE_PRUEBA_O_DESVIRTUA, :RELACION_EMP, :NOTAS_PROBATORIAS, :PARA_PREPARATORIA, :TESTIGO_INCORPORA, :ORDEN_PREPARATORIA, :FECHA_DE_REGISTRO, :SD_ACTIVIDAD1, :SD_ACTIVIDAD2, :SD_ACTIVIDAD3)";
    
$sql = $connect->prepare($sql);
    
////// $sql->bindParam(':ID ACTIVIDAD',$ID_ACTIVIDAD,PDO::PARAM_STR, 25); //////
$sql->bindParam(':CONSECUTIVO_X_CASO',$CONSECUTIVO_X_CASO,PDO::PARAM_INT,25);             //1
$sql->bindParam(':CASO',$CASO,PDO::PARAM_INT,25);                                          //2
$sql->bindParam(':FECHA_ACTIVIDAD',$FECHA_ACTIVIDAD,PDO::PARAM_STR,25);                     //3
$sql->bindParam(':CARPETA',$CARPETA,PDO::PARAM_STR,25);                                    //4
$sql->bindParam(':TIPO_DE_ACTIVIDAD',$TIPO_DE_ACTIVIDAD,PDO::PARAM_STR,25);                //5
$sql->bindParam(':DETALLE_DE_ACTIVIDAD_1',$DETALLE_ACTIVIDAD_1,PDO::PARAM_STR,25);         //6
$sql->bindParam(':DETALLE DE ACTIVIDAD_2',$DETALLE_ACTIVIDAD_2,PDO::PARAM_STR,25);         //7
$sql->bindParam(':RESPONSABLE',$RESPONSABLE,PDO::PARAM_STR,25);                            //8
$sql->bindParam(':QUIEN_REGISTRA',$QUIEN_REGISTRA,PDO::PARAM_STR,25);                      //9 
$sql->bindParam(':PARA_INFORME',$PARA_INFORME,PDO::PARAM_STR,25);                          //10
$sql->bindParam(':ASOCIADO',$ASOCIADO,PDO::PARAM_STR,25);                                  //11
$sql->bindParam(':SOLICITUD_ASOCIADA',$SOLICITUD_ASOCIADA,PDO::PARAM_STR,25);              //  12
$sql->bindParam(':OBSERVACIONES',$OBSERVACIONES,PDO::PARAM_STR);                        //13
$sql->bindParam(':PRUEBA_ALGO',$PRUEBA_ALGO,PDO::PARAM_STR);                            //14  
$sql->bindParam(':QUE_PRUEBA_O_DESVIRTUA',$QUE_PRUEBA_O_DESVIRTUA,PDO::PARAM_STR);      //15
$sql->bindParam(':RELACION_EMP',$RELACION_EMP,PDO::PARAM_STR);                            //16  
$sql->bindParam(':NOTAS_PROBATORIAS',$NOTAS_PROBATORIAS,PDO::PARAM_STR);                  //17
$sql->bindParam(':PARA_PREPARATORIA',$PARA_PREPARATORIA,PDO::PARAM_STR);                    //18
$sql->bindParam(':TESTIGO_INCORPORA',$TESTIGO_INCORPORA,PDO::PARAM_STR);                    //19
$sql->bindParam(':ORDEN_PREPARATORIA',$ORDEN_PREPARATORIA,PDO::PARAM_STR);                  //20    
$sql->bindParam(':FECHA_DE_REGISTRO',$FECHA_DE_REGISTRO,PDO::PARAM_STR);                    //21  
$sql->bindParam(':SD_ACTIVIDAD1',$SD_ACTIVIDAD1,PDO::PARAM_STR);                            //22
$sql->bindParam(':SD_ACTIVIDAD2',$SD_ACTIVIDAD2,PDO::PARAM_STR);                            //23  
$sql->bindParam(':SD_ACTIVIDAD3',$SD_ACTIVIDAD3,PDO::PARAM_STR);                            //24
 
$sql->execute();
```

de antemano gracias por su respuestas. feliz dia.

Comment: Tienes varios errores tipográficos o typos. Por un lado dice `DETALLE_ACTIVIDAD_1` y en otro `DETALLE_DE_ACTIVIDAD_1`, en otra parte `DETALLE_ACTIVIDAD_2` y `DETALLE DE ACTIVIDAD_2` ¡Con espacios!!! Si tienes un buen IDE te lo podría marcar, o bien, selecciona la palabra con doble click y automaticamente seleccionará todas las demás coincidencias y así puedes verificar que las estés escribiendo correctamente.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].